# How can I monitor the number of users having the latest version of my app?

Tags: android, firebase, version, usage-statistics

I have an application that for which I just released an update and want to monitor the number of users who have upgraded to the latest version of my application. Only if a percentage of users have upgraded to the latest version, I would want to push the corresponding changes in my server. How can I monitor this? I have the basic [firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/) setup for my application which does give me information about the number of users of the latest three versions. This is also not very useful because this usage is basically monitored based on the `versionName` and not the `versionCode`. What if I want is information based on the `versionCode`?

Comment: You can see these stats on Developer Console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sign in to your Google Play Developer Console - choose your application you want to check and click Statistics in the left menu, then choose current installs by user and filter by app version. it will look like [-this-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtHpl.jpg)